# Why are Alvars associated with Vishishtadvaita?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita, alwar

Why are Alvars associated with Vishishtadvaita philosophy? Did they themselves say so? Were they initiated from Vishishtadvaita mutts?

Comment: Those people who developed the theory of the philosophy based it on the Alwars' teachings..i think this is the way it is.

Comment: The name Visistadvaita is relatively new.  But Nathamuni derived the philosophy of Visistadvaita from the beliefs and principles found in the poems of the Alwars.  But Nathamuni didn't use the term Visistadvaita.  Even Ramanujacharya, who came 5 generations after Nathamuni in the Guru Parampara, doesn't use the term Visistadvaita in his works as far as I know.

Comment: In any case, the Alwars certainly weren't initiated by Sri Vaishnava Mathams.  The Mathams were founded after Ramanujacharya's time.  But Nammalwar belonged to the Guru Parampara of the Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam.  The Parampara is Vishnu, Lakshmi, Vishvaksena, Nammalwar, Nathamuni, Uyyakondar, Manakkal Nambi, Yamunacharya, Periya Nambi, and Ramanujacharya.  The presence of Lakshmi is why we're called "Sri" Vaishnava.